# With Java reflection how to instantiate a new object, then call a method on it?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm pretty new to Java, and I'm facing a reflection issue.

Let's say i have to dynamically call the method `fooMethod` on an instance of the class `Foobar`

I got so far an instance of `Foobar` with:

```
Object instance = Class.forName("Foobar").newInstance();
```

Let's say I know there's a method `fooMethod` on this object (I can even check this with `Class.forName("Foobar").getDeclaredMethods()` ) , how to call it, please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Method method = getClass().getDeclaredMethod("methodName");
m.invoke(obj);
```

This is in case the method doesn't have arguments. If it has, append the argument types as arguments to this method.
`obj` is the object you are calling the method on.

[See the java.lang.Class docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Comment: What is `getClass`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use reflection

sample `class`

```java
package com.google.util;
class Maths {
  public Integer doubleIt(Integer a) {
    return a*2;
  }
}
```

and use something like this-

**step 1**:- Load `class` with given input name as `String`

```java
Class<?> obj = Class.forName("Complete_ClassName_including_package");
//like:- Class obj = Class.forName("com.google.util.Maths");
```

**step 2**:- get `Method` with given name and parameter type

```java
Method method = obj.getMethod("NameOfMthodToInvoke", arguments);
//arguments need to be like- `java.lang.Integer.class`
//like:- Method method= obj.getMethod("doubleIt", java.lang.Integer.class);
```

**step 3**:- `invoke` `Method` by passing instance of Object and argument

```java
Object obj2 = method.invoke(obj.newInstance(), id);
//like :- method.invoke(obj.newInstance(), 45);
```

---

**YOU CAN DO STEP 2 LIKE THIS ALSO**

(when you ***do not know particular method exists*** in a `class` you check all method by looping method's array)

```java
Method[] methods = obj.getMethods();

Method method = null;

for(int i=0; i < methods.length(); i++) {
  if(method[1].getName().equals("methodNameWeAreExpecting")) { 
    method = method[i];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Purely reflection: [Method.invoke](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).
The other solution is to require the item you are reflectively creating to implement a known interface and cast to this interface and use as normal.

The latter is commonly used for "plugins", the former is not used very often.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by reading about it [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/).

As for the code you are after it is like this (from the same resource):

```
Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
    String mname = m.getName();
    if (!mname.startsWith("test")
        || (m.getGenericReturnType() != boolean.class)) {
        continue;
    }
    Type[] pType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
    if ((pType.length != 1)
        || Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass())) {
        continue;
    }

    out.format("invoking %s()%n", mname);
    try {
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = m.invoke(t, new Locale(args[1], args[2], args[3]));
        out.format("%s() returned %b%n", mname, (Boolean) o);

    // Handle any exceptions thrown by method to be invoked.
    } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
        Throwable cause = x.getCause();
        err.format("invocation of %s failed: %s%n",
               mname, cause.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
((Foobar)instance).fooMethod()
```

Comment: you can only do that if you knew at compile time, that instance is going to be a FooBar - which then means you wouldn't need to use reflection in the first place!

Comment: @Chii: Not necessarly. FooBar could be the most general type from which the one that you're getting through reflection is inheriting. This is how for example JDBC drivers are working and how many plugin architechtures are designed.

Comment: @Chii Also you still would be using reflection for the dynamic instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class.forName("Foobar").newInstance();
```

is now deprecated (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.Module-java.lang.String-)

```
Class.forName("Foobar").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

or if you need a specific constructor:

```
Constructor constructor = Class.forName("java.lang.String").getConstructor(String.class);
String object = (String) constructor.newInstance("Hello");
```