# Replace explicit class name with current class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Consider this class (it is supposed to be immutable):

```
class A {

  normalMethod1(): A{
    const instance = A.staticMethod1();
    return instance;
  }

  static staticMethod1: A(){
    return new this();
  }

}
```

it works fine, but how can I replace `A.staticMethod` with the current class name? Something like `this.staticMethod` (which doesn't work because i get ts2576 error)
And also same thing for the return types, how to replace them with current class?

The reason for this is that if I ever change the class name, I would have to do it in one place instead of everywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782598/with-java-reflection-how-to-instantiate-a-new-object-then-call-a-method-on-it

Comment: You're looking for this ? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863

Comment: so it's not possible yet?

Comment: Are you trying to create a polymorphic factory?

Comment: no idea what that means :D

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {

  normalMethod1(): A{
    const instance = this.constructor.staticMethod1();
    return instance;
  }

  static staticMethod1: A(){
    return new this();
  }

}
```

Further reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648214/5089567

Comment: The `staticMethod1: A()` part looks like a syntax error.